# Javascript dynamically create elements and onclick functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do the following things:

- First, fetch data `paths` on a server. The data contains an array of `path` and the length is unknown.
- Then I create a `list-group` where each `list-group-item` stands for a `path`.
- Finally, I set the `click` function of each of the `list-group-item` which displays the correponding `path` in the data array.

Here's the code

```
var i = 0;
for(path of paths) {
  i++;
  $("#list_path").append('<a id="list-path-' + i + '" class="list-group-item tooltip-button"">' + "Path " + i + '</a>');
  $("#list-path-" + i).click(function() { console.log(path) })
}
```

However, no matter which `list-group-item` I click, only the last `path` element is shown. I guess the problem is that only a pointer of `path` is assigned to the click function, which in the end of the for loop, always points to the last `path`.

How can I set the click function to display different `path`?

Thanks.

Comment: By puting path in `$("#list-path-" + i).click(function() { console.log(path) })` you capture the variable but not it's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use closure

```
var i = 0;
for(path of paths) {
  i++;
  $("#list_path").append('<a id="list-path-' + i + '" class="list-group-item tooltip-button"">' + "Path " + i + '</a>');
  $("#list-path-" + i).click((function(path) {
      // return function wich has own variable path
      return function () { console.log(path) };
  })(path))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this

```
$("#list-path-" + i).click(function() { console.log($(this).text()); })
```

Because of closure, path is the last value of the for loop.